# Выражение с XOR

Tags: javascript, логика

Есть такие выражения:

```
var x = 2
var y = 5
x^y выводит: 7

var x = 5
var y = 7
x^y выводит: 2
```

Как это вычисляется?

Comment: Гуглите по слову XOR. Еще вам понадобится понимание как числа выглядят в двоичной записи.

Answer (score 2):

`XOR` - это логическая операция исключающее ИЛИ. Результат выполнения логической операции XOR будет равен 1, если только один из битов равен 1, во всех остальных случаях, результат равен 0. Таблица истинности имеет следующий вид:

```
x   y   x^y
0   0    0
0   1    1
1   0    1
1   1    0
```

Берём ваш пример и для каждого бита по таблице истинности вычисляем значение результата:

```
x = 2     // В двоичном виде это 010
y = 5     // В двоичном виде это 101
2 ^ 5 = 7 // В двоичном виде это 111
```

Answer (score 2):

XOR - операция сложения по модулю 2.
Вычисляется это так, на выших примерах:
Представим числа в двоичном виде:

```
2 - 010
5 - 101
```

Далее все просто, попарно смотрим биты, каждого числа, там где есть **только одна** единичка в паре, в результат пишем 1, иначе 0.
Смотрим, слева направо:

0 и 1 - единичка одна, в результате 1
1 и 0 - единичка одна, в результате 1
0 и 1 единичка одна, в результате 1

Итого, ещё раз:

```
2 - 010
5 - 101
    111 - 7
```

Второй пример:

```
5 - 101
7 - 111
    010 - 2
```

Ссылки по теме:

[вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E_2)

[хабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/183462/)

Answer (score 0):

Просто как побитовый XOR:

```
var x = 2, y = 5, z = x ^ y;

console.log("%d\n%d\n%d", x, y, z);

x = ("0".repeat(31) + x.toString(2)).slice(-32);
y = ("0".repeat(31) + y.toString(2)).slice(-32);
z = ("0".repeat(31) + z.toString(2)).slice(-32);

console.log("%s\n%s\n%s", x, y, z);

z = (x+y).replace(/(.)(?=.{31}(.))/g, (m,a,b) => a==b ? 0 : 1).slice(0, 32);

console.log(z);
```

Вывод:

```
2
5
7

00000000000000000000000000000010
00000000000000000000000000000101
00000000000000000000000000000111

00000000000000000000000000000111
```